# More than two items optional on AutoLayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I have four label items (subtotal, tax, tips and promotion) which is designed as follows.

Each item is connected to each other. In other words, each label is used top space constraint.

`Promotion` and `Tip` are optional. If user wants to add, then he can. Therefore, I also added constraints for each of these label items' `Height == 0` at the initial state. If any of them is added, then I change the `Height` to `25` to make it visible.

However, you can see if there is no `tip`, then `promotion` position is weird.
I expected to see promotion just under the tax rather than seeing extra white spaces.

I wonder how developers usually handle this issue?

**Before adding Tips**
[image]

**After adding Tips**

[image]

Comment: Try to set low priority for Bottom constraints of Promotion Label ,And Also Set it Greater than or equal to

Comment: @hotspring you can update constant value and shift label up when you hide that label.By taking NSLayoutConstraint outlet.You need to update layout to fill that gap.

Answer (score 1):

The reason was because the `top` and `bottom` of the Tip Label has the same space when it is not hidden, and hiding it by setting it to `height = 0`, it still has the `top` and the `bottom` constraint which made that huge space. you set the `top` constraint of the `Tip Label` to `0` and or as mentioned use `UIStackView` which will auto adjust spacing if one item is hidden.

Answer (score 1):

When you are updating the `Height` constraint of the `Tip` Label. Update the `top vertical space` of the `Promotion` label too.

Set `Promotion` label `top vertical space = 0.0`

**Example :**

```
@interface ViewController () {
    __weak IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *tipLabelHeight;
    __weak IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *promotionLabelTopVerticalSpace;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    tipLabelHeight.constant = 0.0;
    promotionLabelTopVerticalSpace.constant = 0.0;
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

Change the code as per your needs.

Answer (score 1):

When you hide a label by setting it's height as 0, the top and bottom spaces are still there. So when you try to hide a label by setting it's height to 0, you should remove the top spacing of that label also. In this case you should set the top space of 'Tip' label to 0 along with height to 0. So the 'Promotion' label takes the place of 'Tip' label

Answer (score 0):

You might use UIStackView instead of manually manipulating constraints, the stack view manages them automatically, and is perfect for adding and removing subviews laid out in a linear fashion.

Comment: is it possible to provide an example or any similar github source code?

Comment: @hotspring ray wenderlich's stackview tutorial is a nice place to start, from there you could check out Apple's 'Layout Using StackViews' tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Think this is because this kind of display is supposed to be done in a table.
The table would then allocate the spacing accordingly.

Comment: This is actually a footer view in the tableview. Do you think it is a good idea to use `tableview` inside the `tableview` as a footer view?

Comment: Ahhh, in that case, if that is the text in a table then , I would put into its own item.

Comment: I would create custom cells for the smaller ones

Comment: Also, I am skeptical about the use of the footer view, rather just use a normal custom cell.

Comment: Or if you feel that you want to try this shortcut, you can make on if tip hidden, make the tip programmatically decrease the constraint.